# How to create an HTML form with pre-filled in "instructions" that clear when a user clicks in the box?

Tags: html

I have an HTML form as follow:

```
   <form method="POST" action="http://">
 Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" />
 Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="15" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
 </div>
 </form>
```

I would like functionality such that the text fields have instructions in them that clear when a user clicks in the box so that I can save space and remove the words Username and Password from outside the forms.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Yeah, it's just for a standard login form. The user would be able to see his credentials:
Melanie and ****** after entered, just not the instructions: [user] [pass]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called a "placeholder". (if nothing else, just knowing this term will help you search for more info in Google)

In modern browsers which support HTML5, this is a built-in feature which you can use very easily, as follows:

```
<input type='text' name='username' size='15' placeholder='User name' />
```

However, this method only works with up-to-date browsers which support this feature.

Older browsers will need to have some Javascript code to do it. Fortunately, there are a number of scripts you can use, including some written as JQuery plug-ins. The ones I'd recommend are those which tie into the `placeholder` attribute on the input field, so that you can support it natively in the browsers which have this feature and fall-back to Javascript for those that don't.

Try this one: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Answer (score 4):

If you use HTML5 you can do this using the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://">
    <label for="username">Username:</label> 
    <input placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" size="15">
    <label for="password">Password:</label> 
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password" name="password" size="15">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I'd still include the *Username* and *Password* text wrapped in `<label>` tags for accessibility, but you could always hide them with some CSS like this:

```
form {
    position:relative;
}
label {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, there is an attribute in HTML5 that allows this called `placeholder` - read about it here:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html
- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute

This does not require Javascript, but it is not supported by older browsers (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder).

It should be noted that placeholder is ***not*** meant to replace `<label>`s, which you are not using and probably should be.

```
<label for="username">Username:<label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" size="15" />
```

Labels are important for a variety of reasons and it is bad practice to not use them.

Comment: Yeah, there are several things I don't have set up on the form as of yet that I will, just getting it up there for a visual reference in designing the site. Thank you for your tips, however. +!

Comment: Well in that case, labels are a great semantic hook for your CSS so you should *definitely* be using them for your design :)

Answer (score 1):

These are commonly called watermarks and require javascript.

Look at the [jQuery-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom one because I wanted to have a specific behaviour.

https://90dayjobmatch.com/js/jquery.wf.formvaluelabel.js

Usage:

```
$('#signup_job_title').formvaluelabel({text:'eg. Graphic Artist'});
```

Let me know if you have any questions about it.

HTH

Comment: What specific behavior did add to it?

Comment: I wanted it to restore the watermark if the value changed back to its original value. Also, I didn't want the watermark to show if I pre-populated the values (ie. in and edit form). Also, I wanted to be able to test to see if the watermark was actively applied to that element.