# jquery on blur not working for dynamic textbox

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic

I see all sorts of answers online but none of them seem to be working for me.

This is for our local intranet. I'm adding inputs to a form dynamically when a user clicks a button.  I have on focus/blur events but they aren't catching focus and blur on the dynamically created textboxes.  I'm using .on for blur/focus but it still isn't working how I think it should.  I've tried adding "input[type=text]" to the .on function as a selector but that doesn't work either. I've also tried giving the inputs a class and using that instead of input[type=text] but it still won't work.

I'm using the blur/focus to put in default values so the user knows what the textbox is for.  I'm aware of the html5 placeholder but that won't work on IE9 which some of our computers still have.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vf9dC/)

html

```
  <div id="details" class="miSections relative">
        <div class="sectionHeader relative">Details<button id="detailButton" class="newButton" type="button">Add Another Detail</button></div>
            <table id="detailsTable" class="infoTable">                   
               <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="detDate_1" id="detDate_1" class="textarea defaultText" autocomplete="off" title="Detail Date"/></td>
                </tr>                    
            </table>
    </div>
```

css

```
  .infoTable{
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
  }
  .defaultText{
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-style: italic;
  }
```

javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('.textarea').on('focus', function () {
            //using .on('focus','.textarea',function() doesn't work
            if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
                $(this).removeClass('defaultText');
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });

        $('.textarea').on('blur',  function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
                $(this).addClass('defaultText');
                $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
            } else { $(this).removeClass('defaultText'); }
        });

        //fire the blur events to populate the inputs with default values
        blurIt();

        $('#detailButton').on('click', function () {
            $('#detailsTable tr:last-child').after('><tr><td><input type="text" name="detDate_2" id="detDate_2" class="textarea defaultText" autocomplete="off" title="Detail Date"/></td></tr>');

            blurIt();
            countIt();
        });
    });
  function blurIt(){
    $('.textarea').blur();
  }
  function countIt(){
    var inputs = $('.textarea').length;
    console.log(inputs);
  }
```

Comment: you should have used the search feature...

Comment: @A. Wolff are you referring to the search feature on stackoverflow?

Comment: @A.Wolff Next time I post a question I'll be sure to link posts similar to my question that I've already looked at.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802030/creating-an-html-form-with-prefilled-in-instructions)

Comment: I've just typed your exact title in search box for jquery tag and the first topic to come (which is not your) actually answered your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19302151/1414562  Same kind of question is asked hundred times a week (ok, let say a month). But that's ok, happen to anyone

Comment: @A.Wolff You're right I should have found that answer. Now that I know how to use the tags in the search(thanks to you) I'll probably have better results finding what I'm looking for.

Comment: I hope it too. :)  PS: sorry, the edit of your post was to let me remove the downvote...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)'s event delegation syntax.

Change:

```
$('.textarea').on('focus', function () {
//and
$('.textarea').on('blur',  function () {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.textarea', function () {
//and
$(document).on('blur',  '.textarea',function () {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vf9dC/1/)**

Note that you might gain some efficiency by using `$('#details')` instead of `$(document)` in my example.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I thought that by using .textarea first and no selector in .on that it would default to all .textarea in the dom.